# Lexicographically larger strings

Tags: string, lexicographic

I'm trying to understand the concept of lexicographically larger or smaller strings. My book gives some examples of strings that are lexicographically larger or smaller than each other and an intermediary string that is between the two in size.

```
string 1: a
string 2: c
intermediary string: b

string 1: aaa
string 2: zzz
intermediary string: yyy

string 1: abcdefg
string 2: abcdefh
intermediary string: (none)
```

I'm not sure what the requirement is for a string to be lexicographically in between the two strings. Is it that every letter of the intermediary string has to have a larger ASCII value than the corresponding letter of the first string and smaller ASCII value of the corresponding letter of the second string?

For example, "bcdefg" is the intermediary string between "abcdef" and "cdefgh". Can "stuvx" be the intermediary between "stuvw" and "stuvy"?

Comment: Your first example makes no sense, especially in light of the third example. Are you sure it's not meant to be `a,c,b`?

Comment: @paxdiablo: oh, my bad. Fixed it.

Answer (score 4):

Lexicographical ordering simply means dictionary ordering. I say "simply" but there may actually be all sorts of wonderful edge cases such as how you treat apostrophes, what you do with diphthongs, whether you "fold" accented letters into the unaccented ones, such as transforming `{À,Á,Â,Ã,Ä} -> A`. All these rules on how you collate letters will affect the ordering of words as well.

English is fairly easy if you restrict yourself to the twenty-six actual letters of the alphabet. You can consider a word to be "lesser" than another word if, in the first character position that is different between the two, the character from the first word comes before that of the second.

And, in fact, there *is* a solution to the third option provided it doesn't have to be the same length as the others, that of:

```
string 1: abcdefg
string 2: abcdefh
intermediary string: abcdefga
```

Comment: I was trying to write a program that finds an intermediary string between two strings (lowercase a to z only), where one string is lexicographically larger than the other. My program has to determine whether such a string exists. In the case of "abcde" and "abcdf" no string exists because there is no intermediary letter between e and f. My program accounts for all three of the cases in the question above, but the book's CD software is telling me that my program is failing on its test. Are there any other variations of lexicographical lowercase a-z strings besides the ones above?