# return the location of the largest String lexicographically in an ArrayList (Java)

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a problem for a coding class where I must return the location of the largest String (lexicographically) in an arraylist. I have no clue where to start on this, could somebody please help me with the problem?>

Comment: Start by opening your IDE and coding. Once you have specific problems or questions, feel free to ask here. Make sure to take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask as well, before posting. Good luck!

Comment: Probably not the best idea to post School questions as people will be VERY hesitant to provide code. What you will need to do is have a String variable as a reference to the largest known String. Iterate over the ArrayList, and if the current String in iteration is larger than the largest known one currently saved, update the variable.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/ --- A good place to ***start*** would likely be to write a loop to iterate through all the values. Unless you intend to use [Streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#package.description), but that's very likely out of scope for you.

Comment: When people ask questions of this nature without showing the code they've written (as an attempt), I feel it's an insult to the community.. We're not here to do your homework.. Show some effort! Moreso, read the guidelines on asking questions here on Stackoverflow.

Comment: @Taslim I wrote some code and I am not sure why it does not work, should I edit it into the topic or create a new question all together?

Comment: No need to create a new question.. Edit this question and include your code. That'd really help!

Comment: I'd recommend @ZacharyThompson 's suggestion, it's simple enough. To understand what the term 'Lexicography' means (especially as it applies to this question), check this out: [Lexicographically larger strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28801811/lexicographically-larger-strings/)

Answer (score 1):

The [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) class allows you to impose an order on a List very cleanly.

```
List<String> data = new ArrayList<>();
data.sort(Comparator.comparing(String::length).reversed());
data.get(0); // Will return the largest String
```

This will sort the List using the String length() method and reverse the order so that it sorts on largest String first. Do note that you can add a sub-sort so that you can determine how ties are broken (Objects are compared as the same). To do this, sort the data in order of importance, starting with the least.

```
data.sort(Comparator.comparing(String::hashCode));
data.sort(Comparator.comparing(String::length).reversed());
```

Will sort using the hashCode() method then by the length(). This will have the effect of ordering by length, wherein ties are broken by the hashCode (which conventionally attempts to uniquely differentiate objects).